# Hugo config.toml values for params.social in order to display stackoverflow profile

Tags: parameters, hugo

I'm working with Hugo (v0.74.1), just to understand the Static Site Generator works.

I was playing around with the params.social settings, and I notice that there is not good documentation about them, no way to get the supported social params.

https://gohugo.io/variables/site/#example-siteparams

So I have this error:

```
Error: "/codebuild/output/src793937507/src/config.toml:28:1": unmarshal failed: Near line 28 (last key parsed 'params.social.name'): expected value but found "stackoverflow" instead
```

Here is my current settings for the stackoverflow param social

```
[[params.social]]
  name = "stackoverflow"
  url = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
```

I have this one for Github and LinkedIn and both work fine

```
[[params.social]]
  name = "github"
  url = "https://github.com/"

[[params.social]]
  name = "linkedin"
  url = "https://www.linkedin.com/"
```

So my questions is how is the right way to enable stackoverflow links on it? I know that there is some way since I found this website using it https://www.thirtythreeforty.net/posts/2019/12/designing-my-linux-business-card/

Answer (score 0):

The [Hugo-Bingo theme](https://themes.gohugo.io/theme/hugo-bingo/) includes a Stack Overflow "`params.social`" icon on its page.

Its [`exampleSite/config.toml`](https://github.com/gundamew/hugo-bingo/blob/44f3a88c981d47e3400ae2a07c336ddb9c93d066/exampleSite/config.toml#L49-L52) includes:

```
[[params.social]]
  name = "stackoverflow"
  url = "https://stackoverflow.com/story/example"
  weight = 40
```

But [older versions](https://github.com/alvinmejia/website1/blob/52610f5221b188b9d192b1de2aa513867432d893/themes/hugo-bingo/exampleSite/config.toml) included

```
[[params.social]]
  icon = "stackoverflow"
  url = "https://stackoverflow.com/story/example"
  weight = 40
```

Check if one of those syntax work in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did try it, but still has the same error :-(